# How do I show recent blog entries from my Wordpress site inside a webpage?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, wordpress, rss

on an asp.net-mvc website page, i want to show recent blog posts from a wordpress blog.

Similar [to this site](http://architectureforhumanity.org/), i want to show the last few updates of a particular wordpress blog on my website.  kind of like what google reader does i guess, but just for one site and for long posts it should only show a little and have a "click for more" link.

is that something I subscribe on the server and return the html or is it something i should be doing on the client side with jquery  ??

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since Wordpress provides rss feeds you can use them to get the latest posts. The feed is located at http://yourblog.com/feed.

Parsing this feed is a simple task thanks to [SyndicationFeed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.syndication.syndicationfeed.aspx) class. Here's an example:

```
var reader = XmlReader.Create("http://nyqui.st/feed");
var feed = SyndicationFeed.Load<SyndicationFeed>(reader);

Console.WriteLine("Latest posts from " + feed.Title.Text);
foreach(var item in feed.Items)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Title.Text);
}
```

Limiting the posts is a trivial task. Check the length of the text and if it's longer than your threshold, use `string.Substring(0, <limit>)` to cut it.

Comment: @alexn - i just tried to read my feed but it wasn't there.  the wordpress blog is here:  blog.fsf60k.org but when i go to blog.fsf60k.org/feed, i dont see anything

Comment: @alexn - i just tried to read my feed but it wasn't there. the wordpress blog is here: blog.fsf60k.org but when i go to blog.fsf60k.org/feed, i dont see anythin

Comment: @leora Go to `Wordpress Dashboard > Settings > Permalinks` and check if you have selected a `custom structure` like `blog.fsf60k.org/index.php/%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/%postname%/` if this is the case then your feed would be found at `blog.fsf60k.org/index.php/feed`